# IPhone Ipad Dual app Cannot figure out how to specify 2 icons for a dual app

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am writing my first dual app and cannot figure out how to give tell it about the 2 icons to use
I read the following documentation

To specify the icons for your app, add the CFBundleIcons key to your app’s Info.plist file. The contents of that key include a list of filenames intended for use as the primary app icons. The filenames can be anything you want, but all image files must be in the PNG format and reside in the top level of your app bundle. When the system needs an appropriately sized icon, it uses the information in the key to choose the image file whose size most closely matches the intended usage.

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan mentioned, you only need to drag and drop your images into the proper boxes (iPhone icon box, iPhone Retina icon box, etc).

You'll need the PNGs in the proper size, though. You can find information about sizes at the following link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Also if you are using images for your elements (UIButton, UINavigationBar, etc), it's a good practice to name *@2x.png your retina display artwork, like:

navBarBackground.png <- Normal screen

navBarBackground@2x.png <- Retina screen

**Edit:** This way, your application will automatically use the proper image file with the proper screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 4+, then all you need to do is click on the project file at the top of the project navigator, then select the target you are building for, and then drag and drop your icon files into the appropriate boxes in the summary view